# How can I modify compile option when build AOSP

Tags: compilation, android-source, compiler-flags

I'm looking for a way of modifying compile option when build AOSP.
I had tried about below way:

1. Make `application.mk` and Append `APP_CFLAGS`  to  the new mk application.
2. Append `LOCAL_CFLAGS/LOCAL_CPPFLAGS` or `APP_CFLAGS/APP_CPPFLAGS`  to `Android.mk`
3. (this is work when build AOSP for arm but no effective for x86)

   `CFLAGS="-pg -g" CPPFLAGS="-pg -g" make dalvik-host showcommands -j8`

anyone have a little tip for me?